# Android Studio: Sudden Gradle sync error - Misspelled Class Name?

Tags: java, android, gradle, build

My Android Studio project was building fine about an hour prior so I'm not too sure what happened. It appears as though a class is misspelled and I have no clue how to access said code and correct this.

I'm inexperienced with Gradle and to be honest only know that it helps with automation.

I tried updating android studio but this didn't solve the issue. I tried looking online on various other Stack Overflow posts, yet nothing helped solve my issue.

Running with stacktrace gave me the following hint:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/build/gradle/internal/pipeline/TransmormManager
```

The output from attempting to build the project is as follows:

```
Executing tasks: [assemble]


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > com/android/build/gradle/internal/pipeline/TransmormManager

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

Comment: Try clean and rebuild.....if that doesn't work invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Can you share your gradle file?